# Java applet only updates at 10 fps

Tags: java, animation, applet, drawing, appletviewer

One of my recent Java assignments (High school course...) is to make an applet where a border is drawn and a ball moves around the screen bouncing on the borders. I have Fraps installed and it reports that the applet is only running at a mere 10 fps, which makes the animation look extremely mediocre.

My original way of drawing the animation:

1. call my method: `drawScreen()` in `paint()`
2. have a `Thread.sleep(1000/frameRate)` pause in `drawScreen()` for the frame rate, which is passed from the `html`
3. call `repaint()`

This worked wonderfully well and the applet ran like a dream... Until I saw the grading sheet, where it said that I **must not** redraw the screen each time (Maybe it's because the computers are unusually slow and my friends have been complaining that their applets flicker enough to cause eye discomfort, and a lot of tearing all over the place), and I have to draw a ball, then draw another ball the **same colour of the background** to cover it up, calculate the coordinates, and repeat until the applet quits

The problem with this is that

- `repaint()` can't be called
- my animation is capped at 10 fps
- there's no threads available to respond to me clicking close on the appletviewer, or anything else in the applet/viewer.

Is there a way for my animation to run above 10 fps without using `repaint()`?

Comment: BTW - what exactly is your question?

Comment: Problem is now stated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to either implement double buffering or run the applet in a double buffered browser. AppletViewer limited the animation to 10 fps 'cause it doesn't automatically buffer the applets and I was running the applet inside it all this time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't:

   1. Do custom animation in a top-level container such as an `Applet`(/`JAppet`), or `Frame`(/`JFrame`).  Instead put the custom drawing in a `Canvas`/`Panel` or `JComponent`/`JPanel`, then put that component into the top-level container.
   2. Use AWT components in this millennium.
   3. Override `paint()` for the Swing components - it should be `paintComponent(Graphics)`.
2. Don't use `Thread.sleep(n)` on the painting thread.  Instead use a Swing `Timer` and have the action..
3. Call `repaint()`.

Comment: I saw the use of `repaint()` at http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/learn/java/

And I don't think we're doing any Swing stuff after the teacher said something like "I only know enough Applet stuff to teach this, so if you guys want to do anything more advanced, don't ask me, look it up"

Comment: And I don't think I can use this either 'cause my teacher didn't let my friend use double buffering to stop the tearing